# Why there are construction cranes on apparently completed buildings in New York?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-amazing-spider-man

I'm just curious about one thing in *The Amazing Spider-Man*.

There are construction cranes on the rooftops of a number of buildings in New York, which Spider-Man uses to swing across the city. Why are they there when the buildings seem to be already done.

See this video for an example:

Comment: Maybe building has been just finished and construction company hasn't moved down their equipment down yet.

Comment: More important question - how did the operators get inside in the middle of the night in such a short time?

Comment: I bet [the rule of cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) is a big factor.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

At 1:14 mark you can clearly see the building is not finished. There are outside walls missing and the building is still under construction.
Here's a photo of New York building under construction [image]
In the left the buildings have external elevator and cranes. On the right building, at the top, you can see that the crane is still there after all external wall are put in place. It's there to move heavy machines (like AC) to the top at the end (so when all air ducts are in place, power is moved to the top of the building and so on).

Regarding the comment about worker working in the middle of the night. It's New York, city that never sleeps. They were building this 24/7.

Comment: Just to confirm, I have worked in a building in New York (Brooklyn) that had night-time construction crews. That was a renovation job, not initial construction, but the concept still holds. Construction crews definitely also worked through the night sometimes on the 2nd Ave subway (which I had the dubious honor of living near during its construction).

Comment: @KRyan Railway repairs are very often done at night, when there are many fewer trains scheduled (or even none at all).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, but this was the initial construction of that line; there were *no* trains scheduled for several years yet while I was living there.

Comment: It does seem like regardless of the states of the nearby skyscrapers, there are *always* cranes scattered throughout manhattan.

Comment: “They were building this 24/7” — Mr Osborn said it _had_ to be finished by the end of the month or all of his plans would be _RUINED!!!_ Not sure what the plans were, he said something about that not being the concern of minions like us.

Comment: At the rate buildings are damaged/destroyed in the MCU, they need to build more than 24/7 just to keep up!